# How to generate HTML report in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I ran performance test case in jmeter. Now I can see results in 'View Results in Table'. But I also want same results to be saved as html report.

By default jmeter save html report? or is there a way to generate html report?

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 23):

JMeter provide dashboard report which is only available since JMeter 3.0.

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default
>   behavior is to read and process samples from CSV files to generate
>   HTML files containing graph views. It can generate the report at end
>   of a load test or on demand.

To generate Dashboard report follow the instruction below:

[Generating Report Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

Generation from an existing sample CSV log file:

```
jmeter -g <log file> -o <Path to output folder>
```

Generation after load test:

```
jmeter -n -t <test JMX file> -l <test log file> -e -o <Path to output folder>
```

Comment: This is for the apdex reports , not to convert  from table results to html ,

Comment: Thanks dude, been looking for the correct command to ONLY generate the html files for a while, #LEGEND

Comment: ps: @Boikot to generate the CSV file just configure the table listener to output to a file and the table, and once the test completes, run the first commend above to generate the html report.

Comment: I am getting error while doing this: java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Not sure why. can you please help?

Comment: @amit, have you tried [this](https://github.com/julienvollering/MIAmaxent/issues/1). I am not sure if it this is gonna work or not but at least give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @Adnan. I was trying the exact same command. It was failing. I figured it out. I missed to check few columns in 'Summary Report' Configuration which are required for reporting. After I checked them, its working now.

Comment: Note that the `log file` referenced here is *not* the default `jmeter.log` -- you have to use `-l` to generate the `.csv` needed for this.

Comment: if you define your custom properties, then to the command add `-p youpropertiesfile`, in my experience even after I edited `user.properties` located in same `bin` as jmeter, it did not take them (though maybe partly due to me using alias to jmeter.sh).

Comment: Here is a working command to generate HTML report with JMeter:

`jmeter -n -t Jmeter.jmx -l log.csv -e -o ./html`

Note: folder `html` must be empty